# Send identifiers between views and controller method with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Working on an application in laravel that has the capability to create article and add photos. With photos you can add a main one to the article or just add photos to a repository.

Once an article is saved to the database it redirects to a view that will allow you to associate a photo with the recently saved article.

I'm wanting to send an some kind of identifier from the create article view to the photo controller method so it will know what to respond with. Then from the photo controller method send that same identifier to the add photo view so when the photo is submitted to the database the controller knows it's a primary article photo.

I'm trying to avoid having to write several different methods that contain a lot of the same code. I would rather the photo controller be able to tell that the photo is a primary article photo and it knows what to do with it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to have hidden form field in the view that contains the identifier and photo controller will store it in the session that any other controller can read later.